# Is it possible to install h2tp in 2018?

Tags: php, hacklang

As far as I know Hack had `h2tp` utility to complile Hack code to PHP.
But today I couldn't find this command in any of official prebuilt HHVM packages for Ubuntu, and Facebook's blog post link redirects to getting started page. And judging by [this](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/7424#issuecomment-333063882) comment `h2tp` is dead.
But is it still possible to compile from sources/download outdated version of HHVM to somehow use `h2tp`?
And if yes, how do I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible via `docker` on `Ubuntu 18.04`.
The image is [`codeneric/docker-hack-transpiler`](https://hub.docker.com/r/codeneric/hack-transpiler/).